# How i can extract all bitcoin output addresses from tx message?

Tags: transactions, address, script

I want to extract output addresses from tx messages in any bitcoin pcap.

currently, i extract tx messages which it's output script starts with "0x76" or "0xA9", but i don't know how can i extract the other types of op_codes which is introduced here:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script

Answer (score 3):

Most of the output addresses follow one of the following 'standard outputs':

**Legacy Outputs**

1. P2PK: `scriptPubKey: <public_key> OP_CHECKSIG`. Output pays the public key directly and hence does not have a direct address.
2. P2PKH: `scriptPubKey: OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <hash160 of pubkey> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG`. For this kind of output you just need to base58check the `hash160 of pubkey` with version `0x00` and you will get the addresses that starts with 1.
3. P2SH: `scriptPubKey: OP_HASH160 <redeem_script> OP_EQUAL`. You again need to just base58check the `redeem_script` with version `0x05` and you will get an address starting with 3.
4. Multisig: `scriptPubKey: M <public_key1>...<public_keyN> N OP_CHECKMULTISIG`. In this case, you cannot get the addresses as the output pays the public keys directly.

**Segwit Outputs**

1. P2WPKH: `scriptPubKey: <0x00 (version)> <hash160 of pubkey>`. You will need to create a bech32 address using the version and 20-byte redeem script and you will get an address starting with bc1. You can find the python script for bech32 encoding [here](https://github.com/sipa/bech32/blob/master/ref/python/segwit_addr.py).
2. P2SH: `scriptPubKey <version: 0x00> <sha256 of redeem_script>`. Again a bech32 address starting bc1 but the redeem_script is 32 bytes rather than 20 bytes for P2WPKH.
3. P2SH(P2WPKH): `scriptPubKey: OP_HASH160 <redeem_script > OP_EQUAL`. The encoding is same as legacy P2SH. Base58check with `0x05` version. For a more detailed overview on how the 'redeem_script` and addresses are generated for P2SH(P2WPKH) see my other answer [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/55391/p2wsh-witness-v0-scripthash-how-to-derive-an-address/83423#83423).

**OP_RETURN**

Many times people like to encode some data in the Bitcoin blockchain. For that, you use a OP_RETURN opcode. The `scriptPubKey:<OP_RETURN><OP_PUSHDATA1><bytes to push><script>`.

Comment: This is technically not true - you have outputs on the chain that don't match any of the above, the most obvious being P2PK outputs from the early blocks before hash160 addresses were commonly used

Comment: So, Tx messages which contains output scripts start with  0x00, is belongs to which category?
it seems that it is a P2SH (like output scripts which start with 0xA9), but generated output address from that way is not valid.

Comment: @Saeed It's segwit outputs. Legacy P2SH needs to have OP_HASH160 <redeemscript> OP_Equal. However, Segwit P2SH is 0x00 <redeem_script>. For a non-segwit aware client, this looks as if this is anyone can spend output. But Segwit aware clients will look for the scriptSig in the witness section of the transaction.

Comment: @UgamKamat How can i detect between legacy outputs and segwit outputs?
as you said before, there are 6 different way to extract output address based on legacy or segwit outputs. is all these ways?

Comment: @saeed as I said earlier, those are the current STANDARD outputs. Bitcoin is a programmable money, and as a result accept a number of ways in which you can lock the output, but that will not be standard